# @Singleton @Startup @PostConstruct method allowed to block?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

According to the Java EE 6 spec, is the @PostConstruct method on a singleton startup bean allowed to block, or must it return ASAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not forbidden to block, but I think the container startup procedure will block too.

The specs just say in section 4.8.1 "Singleton Initialization" that:

> The container must initialize all such startup-time Singletons before any external client requests (that is, client requests originating outside of the application) are delivered to any enterprise bean components in the application.

So if the `@PostConstruct` method doesn't exit, the container is not ready to serve client requests.